# I have created C# ASP.NET Core Web API - it shows default controller only (weather forecast) rest of the controller is not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I created simple project in C#.

File -> New -> Project -> C# ASP.NET Core Web API.

I can not see the new controller - please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRpjh.png)

I want to see new controllers in Swagger when I add a new controller.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.